# Just My Code Option Does not persist if I close then open Visual Studio 12

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Using Visual Studio 12:

I open up Tools/Options/Debug and check Just My Code and hit save.

I then close VS, and open again.  I open up Tools/Options/Debug and Just My Code is no longer checked.

In other words, it only stays checked as long as I have VS open.  When I close it, I have to reset it the next time I open my project.

Visual Studio 10 saves the option just fine.

Any idea what's up with this?

Greg

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do you by any chance have Reflector addin installed? It seems to sometimes revert this setting.

Answer (score 10):

There is a setting for the .Net Reflector in case you have it installed. Just turn off the checkbox should help.
I added a screenshot showing Visual Studio 2012 with .Net Reflector installed.

[image: Visual Studio 2012]